# The set $\{f\in C([0,1],\mathbb{R})|\|f\|_\infty\leq 1, f\geq 0\}$ is not compact.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I want to show, that the set $M:=\{f\in C([0,1],\mathbb{R})|\|f\|_\infty\leq 1, f\geq 0\}$ is closed and bounded, but not compact.

Therefor this is a counterexample to Heine-Borel.

I am struggeling to show, that it is not compact, because I have no real clue, on how to tackle this.
I would like to try going by the definition and give an open covering of $M$ which has not a finite subcovering.
But I do not know, what an open covering of $M$ would look like, since it contains functions...

Showing that $M$ is bounded ist trivial.
Since $f\geq 0$ and $\|f\|_\infty\leq 1$, we have $0\leq |f(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Therefor $M$ is bounded.

For showing, that $M$ is closed I tried this:

Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset M$ and $(f_n)$ converges in $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$. 
I have to show, that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n=f\in M$.

Therefor $f\geq 0$ and $\|f\|_\infty\leq 1$ and $f\in C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$

$f\geq 0$ is trivial.

For $\|f\|_\infty\leq 1$ I tried:

Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset M$ for all $n\geq m$.
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n=f$ it exists for $\epsilon=1$ a $p\geq m$ such that for every $x\in [0,1]$ holds:

$|f(x)|-|f_p(x)|\leq |f(x)-f_p(x)|<1$.

Hence, $|f(x)|<1+|f_p(x)|\leq 1+\|f_p\|_\infty$

For $p\to\infty$ we have $\|f_p\|_\infty\to 0$ and we conclude $|f(x)|\leq 1$. And as desired $\|f\|_\infty\leq 1$.

Also $f\in C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, because $(f_n)\in C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Is this correct so far?

How can I show, that $M$ is not compact? 
What would an open covering look like?
Can we show it straight from the definition, or might a theorem be useful (I checkt in my notes, but nothing seemed fitting so far).

Hints are apprechiated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to prove the set $M$ is not equicontinuous

Comment: @ChinnapparajR I have not heared of "equicontinuous" so far.

Comment: Because I heard this result: A subset $M$ of $C[a,b]$ is compact if and only if it is closed, bounded and equicontinuous(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to show that $M$  is not sequentially compact. Consider the sequence $f_n(x)=x^n\in M$. Is there any subsequence which is convergent to some $f\in M$?
Note that $x^n\to 0$ when $x\in[0,1)$ and $x^n\to 1$ for $x=1$.

P.S. Your proof for $\|f\|_\infty\leq 1$ needs some revision. Let $\epsilon>0$, then 
ther is $p$ such that $\|f-f_p\|_\infty<\epsilon$ and therefore
$$\|f\|_\infty\leq \|f_p\|_\infty+\|f-f_p\|_\infty< 1 +\epsilon.$$
which implies that $\|f\|_\infty\leq 1$.

Comment: Thank you, therefor I try to get a contradiction to Bolzano-Weierstrass stating, that in a compact metric space every sequence has a convergent subsequence?

Comment: A more general result: If $V$ is a vector space with the norm, then its closed unit ball is compact iff $V$ is finite dimentional

Comment: @ChinnapparajR This question is not taken from a functional-analysis course.

Comment: In metric spaces, compact and  sequentially compact are equivalent.

Comment: Ok I understand! Just I recall this to you

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. When I take $f_n(x)=x^n$ the Limit would be $f(x)=\begin{cases} 1\quad\text{for x=1}\\ 0\quad \text{for}\,\, x\in [0,1)\end{cases}$. Hence $f$ is not continuous. (This applies of course for every subsequence of $f_n$.)

Comment: @Cornman Yes, that's the point.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. Is my argument for $M$ beeing closed correct? I wonder, because with the same argument, I could show, that $\|f\|_\infty\leq c$ for what ever $c\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @Cornman See my P.S.